# How can I tell how much time I've spent in an Xbox One game?

Tags: xbox-one

I've been trying to figure out how many hours I've played the games on my Xbox One console, and I can't find an universal way to do so with the console's built-in software.

To contrast, the Steam application tells you how long you've spent running each game, and the 3DS's Activity Log and Wii U's Daily Log apps give you the same info and break it down by days weeks, and months. I can't seem to find anything similar on Xbox One, except for game-specific in-game counters (which are arguably more accurate, but not at all universal).

Have I missed a counter somewhere in the UI, or something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting with the [February 2015 software update](http://news.xbox.com/2015/02/xbox-one-xbox-one-february-system-update) (which came out after I wrote the question and accepted [TZHX's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/199171/3275)), this information is available on the console itself.

As of April 2019, here's what you do:

1. Highlight the game's icon on the Home screen or My Games And Apps
2. Open the app options menu, such as by using the controller's hamburger Menu button
3. Select Go To Official Club
4. On the new screen, change from the Feed tab at top to Progress by scrolling left or right
5. Change from the Achievements sub-tab at left to Stats by scrolling down to the lower area, then left to the sub-tab list, then down

From here, you can see total time played as well as other game-specific statistics, and you can also choose to Compare With Friends.

Comment: Has this since been removed?  It does not seem to work for me.  Perhaps it is game-dependent?  Other stats are there but no play time.

Answer (score 4):

Strangely, it doesn't seem like this information is available on the console itself.

I say strangely, because it is tracked and available to view under the "Achievements" page in the SmartGlass Companion application for tablets (at least, it is for the iOS version). But it doesn't appear to be visible anywhere on the console.

[image]

Comment: I verified that the Windows apps (Phone and 8) also display the time in each game under Achievements. It's very strange indeed that this info isn't on the console or Xbox.com...

Answer (score 1):

I found it through constant searching. go to the friends tab and the choose a game (usually the ones displayed are those friends have played) after selecting the game, select view leaderboard, and your hours played as well as other progression stats for the game are shown in comparison to friends' stats.

Comment: Oops, I wrote [my self-answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/210655/3275) and only after that realized you said the same thing! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple answer: Select a game > Game Hub > Achievements. The play time should be there on the Windows 10 Xbox One update. :D

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on the one app I know for sure. I think it is possible on the Xbox too. Go into achievements and then select the game you want and then you scroll down to find one that says time played.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Now you have to menu click on the game, go to game club, then click on progress, which will show achievements, then scroll over to stats. I believe it only shows time played for XB1 games, not 360s.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to your profile in the achievements tab, you can select a specific game and it will show you the percentage of the achievements you've gotten, as well as time spent on the game, and the achievements locked and unlocked by you.

Comment: This was mentioned years ago.