# User activity on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

I was wondering is there's a way you can view your activity on the Xbox One X. I need to know exactly what time I was on my Xbox on a specific date and how long I was on for.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways to get detailed information about time spent playing on Xbox One, you can receive a weekly email report and check the information on the site

**1) The first is to set up a family group and add yourself to it:**

- Go to [Family Microsoft](https://family.microsoft.com/) and create a group with a different Microsoft account
- Find your account and select **Activity**
- Select **Manage** and set **Activity reporting** to **ON**

*You can also turn off email reporting, switch **Email me weekly reports** to **OFF***

You can find more details on [this website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12441/microsoft-account-see-child-device-activity)

**2) The second way shows information about a specific game, you can compare it with friends**

You can get statistics for a given game directly from your Xbox, but you will only have statistics for a given game, not all games activity. Check the answer to the previously asked question: [How can I tell how much time I've spent in an Xbox One game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/210655/241827)